# Is a sleeve could be a eartlhy body ?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I recently watched a new serie called Altered Carbon. They are keep talking about "sleeve".

As I understood it could translated as a earthly body, as in [the serie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2261227/) people are able to save their mind and consciousness into a device that could be uploaded in any human shell.

But I didn't find anything linking earthly body and sleeve according both Cambridge and Oxford dictionaries.

Am I wrong or somebody could explain this to me ?

Ludovic ;)

Comment: The non-standard usage 're-sleeved', including scare quotes, is mentioned in the synopsis. I'd argue it's off-topic as outside the lexicon.

Comment: _Altered Carbon_ depicts a dystopian future in its own universe. This usage of _sleeve_ is unique to the series, but is easily understood by the audience. A new physicsl body is put on like a garment.

Comment: Klingon is spoken in Star Trek - it too is fiction and outside the english lexicon.

Answer (score 1):

*Altered Carbon* is a work of science fiction. It is common practice in science fiction and other fantasy genres to invent words. Part of the reason for this practice is that fantasy deals with objects, creatures, effects, and concepts that do not exist in the world we know. In order to advance the story, the author has a need to give them names.

In the case of stories which are set in a place and time related to our own (such as a possible future or an alternate timeline), some of these invented words are chosen to be as believable as possible. In a future world where medicine has advanced to the point where a body has come to be thought of as an expensive form of clothing, it is easy to believe that English speakers would adapt the word *sleeve* to mean such a "wearable body". It is believable because it uses *sleeve* in a way that is analogous to the way we use it now. We already speak of putting not only an [arm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeve) into a sleeve, but also a [phonograph record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_sleeve), or a [bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-liter_bottle), or two pieces of [tubing](http://www.doughty-engineering.co.uk/cgi-bin/trolleyed_public.cgi?action=showprod_T14900), or [cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_sleeve), or [coins](https://www.coincommunity.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=281911).

Other words which were similarly repurposed by science fiction writers on the strength of an analogy include *[thread](http://pern.wikia.com/wiki/Thread)*, *[alien](https://io9.gizmodo.com/31-essential-science-fiction-terms-and-where-they-came-1594794250)*, and *[credit](https://io9.gizmodo.com/31-essential-science-fiction-terms-and-where-they-came-1594794250)*.

(The reverse also frequently happens. Fantasists invent new words which are later adopted outside of their genre: *[grok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok#Etymology)*, *[nerd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerd#Etymology)*, *[robot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot#Origin_of_the_term_'robot')*, *[utopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia#Etymology)*, *[airlock](http://www.viviancook.uk/Words/SFWords.htm)*, *[cyberspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberspace#Origins_of_the_term)*.)

Answer (score 0):

Altered Carbon is using the word "sleeve" to refer to the body one's consciousness is uploaded into. This usage of "sleeve" does not exist outside of the series.

In general, a "sleeve" can mean a case that you put something else into. Thus, when the consciousness is put into the body, the body is referred to as the "sleeve". Again, though, this is not a meaning of the word "sleeve" outside of Altered Carbon.

Answer (score 0):

A phonograph record, CD, DVD, etc. may be put into a cover made of paper, cardboard, plastic, etc. called a "sleeve"*.  So (in that fictional world) they similarly say that a body is like a sleeve that you can put your personality into.

[image: sleeve]

> *Is it true that you cannot find that defintion in a dictionary?